# pumping lemma division cases

Tags: computer-science, pumping-lemma

If I got a language that I want to classify as "nonregular" using pumping lemma

the problem that I'm facing with this algorithm is the following:

when you divide the string S that you choose(that is greater or equal than the pumping length p) to three parts x, y and z,
you shouldn't do that multiple times with say 3 cases or 4 cases,

because if I got only one case of dividing them that satisfies the division criteria of the theory and I got a contradiction that's enough right ??

for example here in the picture, we only need the first case, why? well the division criteria of the theorem has been met, what do I mean by criteria ?? well 1- the length of y>0 2- the length of xy>0 if that happens (even in one case) and I got a string that don't belong to the original language then I should stop right ??

[image]

Comment: You cannot simply choose a division that meets the requirements of the lemma; you must show that no matter how you divide the word, if your division meets the requirements, then you can pump the word to get something not in the language. What is the language in this case?

Comment: L = {a^n,b^n}, but I didn't understand do I stop after case 1 and why?

Comment: Okay; I’ll write up a fairly detailed explanation.

Comment: See if what I’ve written so far helps to clarify matters.

Comment: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Start by assuming that $L$ is regular. In that case it has a pumping length $p$, and the pumping lemma says that if $w\in L$, there is some way to decompose $w$ as $w=xyz$ such that $|y|\ge 1$, $|xy|\le p$, and $xy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. To get a contradiction, thereby showing that $L$ cannot in fact be regular, we’ll find a word $w\in L$ such that **no matter how** we divide it as $w=xyz$ with $|y|\ge 1$ and $|xy|\le p$, there will be some $k\ge 0$, such that $xy^kz$ is **not** in $L$.

One word that does the trick is $w=a^pb^p$. Suppose that $a^pb^p=xyz$, where $|y|\ge 1$ and $|xy|\le p$. Then $xy$ is at most the first $p$ characters of $w$, so it consists entirely of $a$s. Thus, there are non-negative integers $r$ and $s$ such that $x=a^r$, $y=a^s$, $r+s\le p$, and $s\ge 1$. That means that $z$ must be all the rest of $w$, so $z=a^{p-r-s}b^p$, and $w=xyz=a^ra^sa^{p-r-s}b^p$.

The pumping lemma says that if $L$ really is regular, $xy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$, so let’s see what $xy^kz$ actually is:

$$xy^kz=a^r(a^s)^ka^{p-r-s}b^p=a^{r+ks+p-r-s}b^p=a^{p+(k-1)s}b^p\,.$$

This is in $L$ if and only if $p+(k-1)s=p$, and this is the case if and only if $k=1$. If we take $k=0$, for instance, we have $a^{p-s}b^p$, and since $s\ge 1$, $p-s\ne p$, and this word is not in $L$. If we take $k=2$, we get $a^{p+s}b^p$, and again this is not in $L$, since $p+s>p$.

Note that I didn’t choose any specific decomposition of $w$: what I did applies equally to **every** decomposition $a^pb^p=xyz$ that meets the two fundamental requirements that $|y|\ge 1$ (so that pumping actually changes the word) and $|xy|\le p$.